# Subplots in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

how do I create one plot with 2 seaborn plots (subplots)

How to merge 2 seaborn plots into 1?

```
plt.figure(figsize = (12, 6))
ax = sns.scatterplot(x = model1.fittedvalues, y = model1.resid)
plt.grid()
ax.axhline(y=0, color='r', linewidth=4) 
ax.set_xlabel("vysvětlovaná proměnná");
ax.set_ylabel("residua");


plt.figure(figsize = (12, 6))
ax = sns.distplot(a = model1.resid, bins = 40, norm_hist=True,)
plt.grid()
ax.set_title("Histogram reziduí", fontsize = 25);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your subplots anyway you like (using `plt.subplots()`, `fig.add_subplot()`, `GridSpec`, you name it), then pass a reference to the axes to the seaborn functions using `ax=<your axes reference>`

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize = (24, 6))
sns.scatterplot(x = model1.fittedvalues, y = model1.resid, ax=ax1)
ax1.grid()
ax1.axhline(y=0, color='r', linewidth=4) 
ax1.set_xlabel("vysvětlovaná proměnná");
ax1.set_ylabel("residua");

sns.distplot(a = model1.resid, bins = 40, norm_hist=True, ax=ax2)
ax2.grid()
ax2.set_title("Histogram reziduí", fontsize = 25);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could better to define subplots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

x = np.array([4,3,2,3])
y = np.array([5,1,6,4])

**fig, sub = plt.subplots(2,1)**

plt.figure(figsize = (12, 6))
sns.scatterplot(x, y , **ax=sub[0]**)

ax.axhline(y=0, color='r', linewidth=4) 
ax.set_xlabel("vysvětlovaná proměnná")
ax.set_ylabel("residua")



plt.figure(figsize = (12, 6))
sns.distplot(x, bins = 40, norm_hist=True, **ax=sub[1]**)

ax.set_title("Histogram reziduí", fontsize = 25)
```

[image: Subplot]